# Windows Server 2019 Domain Controller - "Application-Aware" Backups Using VSS

Tags: active-directory, backup, domain-controller, windows-server-2019

This is a theoretical question regarding "application-aware" backups for Windows Server 2019 domain controllers (and other VMs) that can be made through third-party applications such as Veeam, Nakivo, etc.  (NOT asking the correct ways to backup/restore a DC!)

In a multi-DC environment where at least one DCs is in a normal operational state, assume that a single DC becomes broken at the OS level and is restored from backup.

Even with a correct "application-aware" backup/restore of this VM, the DC cannot simply be restored and booted.  (If it is, it will run into USN rollback issues and replication will fail).  Instead, it must be booted into DSRM and a registry key set to enable a non-authoritative restore.  (see [here](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100005450))

I may be wrong, but in this scenario, is an application-aware backup even necessary?  If so, why?  It would seem not necessary since the restored DC must still pull down all AD data to itself anyway.  OR, does using application-awareness also ensure that the OS itself makes a correct backup (and in that case, all VM backups should use it, regardless of if they have AD, DBs, etc)?

If an application-aware backup is NOT necessary in this scenario (with a single DC failure), in what instances would it be?  Am I correct in thinking that it's really only beneficial if you need to do an authoritative restore (for example, if ALL DCs go down or AD itself becomes corrupted and replicated)?

Answer (score 1):

I should have Googled more.  It turns out that an application-aware backup IS actually important for more than just preserving the state of AD on a domain controller.

A backup that is NOT application-aware is more or less what you'd get if you did an hard power off of a machine without doing a clean shutdown, as if the machine suddenly lost power.  It is very possible that there could be some OS file being changed that could become corrupt.

Therefore, attempts should be made to make all VM backups "application-aware", whether that be through MS's VSS or through VMware's quiescing mode.

So to answer my own questions:

1. Yes, application-aware backups ARE important for a DC backup (and for any VM backup, really).  It not only preserves the state of AD, but also of the OS itself.
2. As such, I think the authoritative / non-authoritative restore (and the single DC restore in a multi-DC environment) has little to do with the application-aware backup.

**Summary: Do application-aware backups if you can, unless you know for certain that the VM won't benefit.**

Sources:
https://helpcenter.veeam.com/archive/backup/95/vsphere/transaction_consistency.html
https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/application_aware_processing.html?ver=95u4